# Button event Excel

Tags: excel, vba

My intent is to fill the underlying basis of the data table  taken from the rows to the pressure (located button which says "BUTTON") and where I "No." increment automatically.

I used this code so far but it doesn't copy to the next free row. How could I do that?

```
Sub Range_Copy()
    Range("D15:F15").Copy Range("D20:F20")
    Range("D15:F15").Value = ""
End Sub
```

[image: My excel WorkSheet]

Comment: You can do this with VBA. But I have to tell you that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You have to write your own code and if you have specific problems with your code, then you can come back here to get help. If you need to learn how to code VBA then this might not be the right place.

Comment: I try this Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D5")
Set dest = Range("F3:F5)
dest.Value = r.Value.                                                          But the question remains of how to copy cells each time the line below.

Comment: Sub Range_Copy()

    Range("D15:F15").Copy Range("D20:F20")
    Range("D15:F15").Value = ""

End Sub    This work but i'd like to copy in Range in empty row

Comment: First of all: Never add code into comments (nobody can read that) you can edit your question to insert code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it. You just needed to find the last used row in that column.

I added some comments for you to learn why I changed some things. Also I used `With Worksheets(...)` to make sure that all changes are made on a specific worksheet. See [here about the `with` block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) and how it is used.

Change `YOUR-SHEET-NAME-HERE` to the name of your worksheet.

```
Sub Range_Copy()
    Dim LastUsedRow As Long
    Dim InputRange As Range

    With Worksheets("YOUR-SHEET-NAME-HERE")
        LastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            ' find last used (non empty) row in column D

        Set InputRange = .Range("D15:F15")
            ' set the input range to a variable so in case we
            ' need to change that range later there is only
            ' one position that we need to change

        InputRange.Copy
            ' copy the input range

        .Range("D" & LastUsedRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            ' Paste in column D (LastUsedRow + 1 = next empty row)
            ' PasteSpecial xlPasteValues only pastes the values no format
            ' (so the input range can be formated differently)

        InputRange.ClearContents
            ' using .value = "" dosen't really clear the cell.
            ' It remains an empty string which can cause issues later
            ' Therefore we use .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for everything:

copy value:

```
Sub Range_Copy()
    Dim x As Long
    x = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Range("E15:G15")
        .Copy Destination:=Range("D" & x)
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Copy WorkSheet and rename the copy:

```
Option Explicit
Sub NewSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Template")
    Set sh = Sheets("Dati")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    For i = 5 To Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If sh.Range("K" & i).Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Template").Copy After:=sh
            ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("K" & i).Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value = sh.Range("L" & i).Value
        End If
        If i = 23 Then Exit For
    Next i

End Sub
```